# AcquireTokenSilent always Failed to acquire token silently

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, adal

Using ADAL I have two `AuthenticationContext` using a Token Cache persisted in SQL.

Using `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` it writes the Token in database, but when using `AcquireTokenSilent` I always get

> Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken

Here are the details for replication the issue:

I create a Context

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority, new AzureAdalCache(companyId, _entries, _unitOfWork));
```

Then I AcquireToken By Authorization

```
authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, new Uri(redirectUri), _clientCredential);
```

At this point, it saves an entry in the database

Then if I call this I get an exception.

```
authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(_authority, _clientCredential, new UserIdentifier(companyId.ToString(), UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)).AccessToken;
```

I also tried with the same result:

```
authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(_authority, _clientId).AccessToken;
authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(_authority, _clientCredential, UserIdentifier.AnyUser).AccessToken;
```

I Post my `AzureAdalCache` implementation in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/289b7f6a3423c54e7022).

Each entry of the Cache is [like this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/583a78d1f07c2fa1c101).

What Am I missing?

**Update**

Based on answer of comments of @vibronet I have this

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority, new AzureAdalCache(companyId, _entries, _unitOfWork));
authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, new Uri(redirectUri), _clientCredential, _eWSResource);
string result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(_eWSResource, _clientId, UserIdentifier.AnyUser).AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was that basically I was using Common Authority  `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize` in my App. It works for AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode() but not for AcquireTokenSilent().

So I needed it to save the TenantId when call AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode() and an authority use an authority like `https://login.windows.net/<tenant ID>/oauth2/authorize`when call AcquireTokenSilent(). This way the same code above works.

Comment: Also note that, in some versions of ADAL, the GUID that is the TenantId and the user's UniqueId are case sensitive in that they must be lowercase for the cache to load them correctly.

Comment: any sample code would help. because AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync will have different parameters.

Comment: For me was enough to just stick in the Authority url as this one: `https://login.windows.net/<tenant ID>/`

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the call:

```
authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(
    _authority,
    _clientCredential,
    new UserIdentifier(companyId.ToString(), UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)
).AccessToken;
```

The UserIdentifier must match the value in the cache, and CompanyID does not sound like any of the identifier you get back for the token.

Please take a look at the sample I pointed you to on the other thread, and specifically on the identifier used in call to AcquireTokenSilent in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs

You don't get to choose which identifier to use in that call, that is determined by what claims AAD issues. The only identifiers you can choose are at the cache instance level, not in individual AcquireToken* calls.

Comment: Thanks @vibronet. I see I was doing very bad.
I should use 
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

But... how do I access to ClaimsPrincipal.Current in the Background Job? I am getting  "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: You have to save he correct value somewhere and pass it along :) or you have to expose a web API if you want to trigger the logic on demand

Comment: But... how can I get the Claim in the Website if I dont have Azure Authentication in my the Website?

I mean, the users in the website are local for the app (using ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework). I am allowing the user to register his azure AD for some background job, but I wont change the authentication and claims in  the website.

So any idea about what should I pass as UserId for AcquireTokenSilent()?

Comment: You are the one deciding what is the context. If you have a user session with a local account, you can create an ADAL cache instance just for that local account. At that point you don't even need to specify a useridentifier when you call acquiretokensilent given that there is no ambiguity. That is really how the cache in our sample is implemented

Comment: As I said in the post I already tried it with the same result.

I call             authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode, new Uri(redirectUri), _clientCredential, _eWSResource);

And then 
authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(_eWSResource, _clientId);

It fails saying I should call AcquireToken(). I am not passing userId, but the TokenCache receives the "User Id" as parameter.

Comment: In the post you were passing the authority in place of the resource. Also, you have to pass useridentifier.anyuser. Another thing you might want to do is to turn on logging to see exactly were things fall apart.

Comment: I just updated the Question with the current code. With that code I have the same behavior. Any Idea about what can It be or how can I enable logging for try to find whats wrong?

Comment: See the logs section of the read me of https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet

Comment: I really cannot understand this thing :(

Using the logger I can see It serialize and use the Token with a GUID I never pass "d529b8e4-44cd-4fc5-93e2-637dd20341a9" and when I consult with UserIdentifier.AnyUser it querys for a Token with Guid "6a360032-c1f1-4054-b8da-304cbbab4a78". 

I dont understand why using AnyUser it query  for this Id

Comment: I sent the message to you. Also created a  simplified repo replicating the issue. https://github.com/ricardopolo/AdalIssue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in ASPNetCore (1.0) and the reason was that I wasn't storing the authentication token after logging in. I solved it by adding `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` in the Startup class and changing my Response ype to `ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken`.

Hope it helps.

Sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/blob/aspnet10/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIdConnect-DotNet/Startup.cs#L100

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: Fixed it @KevinR.

Answer (score 1):

Check if token is existing in cache else sign out and ask user to sign in.

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority,
                        new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
                    if (authContext.TokenCache.Count == 0)
                    {
                        authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
                        CosmosInterface.Utils.AuthenticationHelper.token = null;
                        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question - but for me, I needed to clear my cookies on the client and then it forced the browser to re-auth and everything was fine again.